# MysQL Update Query Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run the following SQL query in phpMyAdmin:

```sql
UPDATE registration SET key=1 sandr='aaa' where Username='qaz'
```

I have also tried using commas in separating the two fields:

```sql
UPDATE registration SET key=1, sandr='aaa' where Username='qaz'
```

Table schema:

```
registration (table name)
------------------------------------------
key  | sandr | Username (column names)
1    | 'aaa' | 'qaz'    (valid details in the table
```

Here are my table entries:

[image: This is my table entries]

And this is my table structure:

[image: This is my table structure]

Environment:

- My PHP version is 5.3.5
- Apache version is 2.2.17
- MySQL version is 5.5.8

Comment: do not use password varchar for security ............

Comment: Key is a reserved word, so a poor choice for a column name in my view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example is correct. Try formatting it like this:

```html
UPDATE `registration` SET `key` = 1, `sandr` = 'aaa' WHERE `Username` = 'qaz'
```

Answer (score 0):

May be in username column with gaz you have space?
Try:

```
UPDATE registration SET key=1, sandr='aaa' where Username LIKE 'qaz%'
```